# R Weighted moving average with partial averages

Tags: r, performance, moving-average

I am trying to code in R a(centered) weighted moving average function that returns me a vector of the same size than the input vector.
The following code almost gives me what I want but it does not work for the first and last values of my vector

```
set.seed(0)
len=10
x=floor(l*runif(l))
weights=c(1,3,0,3,1)
weights=weights/sum(weights)
rollapply(x,width=length(weights), function(x) sum(x*weights),align="center")
na.omit(filter(x,sides=2,weights))
```

Setting partial=TRUE in the rollapply function is sort of what I want to do. Anyway it does not work since my function does not support an x of changing sizes.

I could the latter and manually add the sides computations with a loop. It would work but I would like to find a nicer (computationally faster) way to do it.

For a more rigorous description of my needs here is a mathematical version

r is the vector my function would return

x and the weights w as inputs :

[image]

Comment: Questions: What is `l` in the code snippet you provided? Is it supposed to be `len`.  You may find `sample()` helpful.

Comment: What do you mean your function does not support an x of changing sizes?  What is the `x` object in your code, and what is your desired output?

Comment: Can't you pad your original vector on both sides with `(l-1)/2` `NA`'s and then use `rollaply` or `ma` with `na.rm`?

Comment: W index is from negative L to L so L is already (length(weights vector)-1) /2 and what you describe is actually what I already do and try to speed up and improve

Comment: And don’t want na s on the sides I want partial moving average as my formula does

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With Rcpp, you can do:

```
#include <Rcpp.h>
using namespace Rcpp;

// [[Rcpp::export]]
NumericVector roll_mean(const NumericVector& x,
                        const NumericVector& w) {

  int n = x.size();
  int w_size = w.size();
  int size = (w_size - 1) / 2;

  NumericVector res(n);
  int i, ind_x, ind_w;

  double w_sum = Rcpp::sum(w), tmp_wsum, tmp_xwsum, tmp_w;

  // beginning
  for (i = 0; i < size; i++) {
    tmp_xwsum = tmp_wsum = 0;
    for (ind_x = i + size, ind_w = w_size - 1; ind_x >= 0; ind_x--, ind_w--) {
      tmp_w = w[ind_w];
      tmp_wsum += tmp_w;
      tmp_xwsum += x[ind_x] * tmp_w;
    }
    res[i] = tmp_xwsum / tmp_wsum;
  }

  // middle
  int lim2 = n - size;
  for (; i < lim2; i++) {
    tmp_xwsum = 0;
    for (ind_x = i - size, ind_w = 0; ind_w < w_size; ind_x++, ind_w++) {
      tmp_xwsum += x[ind_x] * w[ind_w];
    }
    res[i] = tmp_xwsum / w_sum;
  }

  // end
  for (; i < n; i++) {
    tmp_xwsum = tmp_wsum = 0;
    for (ind_x = i - size, ind_w = 0; ind_x < n; ind_x++, ind_w++) {
      tmp_w = w[ind_w];
      tmp_wsum += tmp_w;
      tmp_xwsum += x[ind_x] * tmp_w;
    }
    res[i] = tmp_xwsum / tmp_wsum;
  }

  return res;
}
```

I use this function in one of my packages.

Just put that in a `.cpp` file and source it with `Rcpp::sourceCpp`.

Comment: Nice thanks I’ll give it a try on Monday I should be quick since it’s in c++ I’ll tell you the result in Monday

Comment: It works and it is very fast ! Awesome! 
Merci beaucoup!

Comment: For 1 million observations and more it is actually more than 5000 times faster than R rollapply function !

Comment: If you want to learn more about Rcpp, see this presentation: https://privefl.github.io/R-presentation/Rcpp.html

Comment: @MaxFt Just saw your issue with this code I gave you. I shoud have warned you: this code won't work is `x` is not longer than `w` (the beginning and end parts mustn't overlap). And you may want to use `w` with an odd length (so that it has a middle).